# App Crashes when attempting to present sheet over view when using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, xcode11, ios13

I am trying to present a view over another view in SwiftUI using [.sheet()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/sheet). When this runs my app crashes **with no stack trace even when run on a simulator** and this error displayed:

```
    EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

I have already determined that the view that is being presented is not the problem by attempting to present Text("Test") instead of my custom view but I still get the same error.

```
.sheet(isPresented: self.$isPresenting) { () -> Text in
    return Text("This is a test")
 }
```

This is the code that sets up the view and attempts to present another view **when the green button is pressed**. It looks like this on the device:

[image]

```
struct WeekView: View {

    @ObjectBinding var currentMealPlan = MealPlan(totalMealExchanges: 0, totalGraciesMeals: 0)
    @State var isPresenting = false
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{
        VStack{


            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Text("Meals at Gracies remaining: ?/\(currentMealPlan.totalGraciesMeals)")
                Text("Meal Exchanges Remaining: ?/\(currentMealPlan.totalMealExchanges)")
            }



            List{
                Section(header: Text("Monday")) {
                    HStack{


                        MealView(meal: "Breakfast", location: "Dorm ", color: Color.green)
                            .tapAction {
                                self.isPresenting.toggle()

                        }
                        .sheet(isPresented: self.$isPresenting) { () -> Text in
                                    return Text("This is a test")
                                }



                        MealView(meal: "Lunch", location: "Gracies", color: Color.blue)
                        MealView(meal: "Dinner", location: "Salsarita", color: Color.yellow)



                    }
                }


  Section(header: Text("Tuesday")) {
                    Text("Hello World")

                }

                Section(header: Text("Wednesday")) {
                    Text("Hello World")

                }

                Section(header: Text("Thursday")) {
                    Text("Hello World")

                }
                Section(header: Text("Friday")) {
                    Text("Hello World")

                }

                Section(header: Text("Saturday")) {
                    Text("Hello World")

                }

                Section(header: Text("Sunday")) {
                    Text("Hello World")

                }


            }

 }.navigationBarTitle("This Week")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {

            }, label: {
                Text("Help")
            }))

    }

    }
}





struct MealView: View {
    @State var meal: String
    @State var location: String
    @State var color: Color
    @State private var showPopover = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Rectangle()
                .fill(color)
            VStack{
                Text(meal)
                    .bold()
                Text(location)
                    .lineLimit(2)
                    }


        }
    }}
```

```
class MealPlan: BindableObject   {

    let willChange =  PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>

    var totalMealExchanges: Int {didSet {willChange.send()}}
    var totalGraciesMeals: Int {didSet {willChange.send()}}

    init(totalMealExchanges: Int, totalGraciesMeals: Int) {
        self.totalGraciesMeals = totalGraciesMeals
        self.totalMealExchanges = totalMealExchanges
    }

}
```

Comment: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION usually happens because the compiler is expecting to find something where there is nothing. It could be that you're force unwrapping a nil, could be an array index out of bounds, could be that you're referencing something that was recently deallocated by ARC or otherwise. Those are 3 of the common causes

Comment: Thanks for the response! I thought that could be the case which is part of the reason why I tried presenting a simple label instead of my custom view (where I'm decoding JSON and appending values to an array) but I still have the issue. I'm not sure what could be being deallocated since I'm using SwiftUI Views and @State vars both of which SwiftUI is supposed to handle behind the scenes (at least that's my understanding how it works).

Comment: You should add your `MealPlan` implementation to your post, otherwise we cannot reproduce the problem. If we cannot reproduce, it is impossible to pinpoint where the crash can be coming from. If you cannot disclose your MealPlan, try reducing its implementation to its minimum expression. In the process, the crash might go away and you will have a better idea where the issue is coming from.

Comment: @kontiki just added the MealPlan class to the bottom of the post

Answer (score 2):

I tried it on a simulator (iPhone Xr), and it does not crash. I am using Xcode 11 Beta 4. What is your setup?

I did spot something that is wrong though. You are calling willChange in didSet, but you should really call it before that change is made, in willSet. You should change:

```swift
var totalMealExchanges: Int {didSet {willChange.send()}}
var totalGraciesMeals: Int {didSet {willChange.send()}}
```

to:

```swift
var totalMealExchanges: Int {willSet {willChange.send()}}
var totalGraciesMeals: Int {willSet {willChange.send()}}
```

Comment: Thanks for point out the willSet issue :), I just fixed that baed on your recommendation. I'm running Xcode 11 beta 4 as well and I've been testing the app in the iPhone XR simulator. Since the app didn't crash for you did the modal present or did nothing happen?

Comment: Yes, it does present.

Comment: wow, that's really strange. Did you just copy the code I put in my question?

Comment: Yes, I copied and pasted. I also corrected the `willSet`,and added the missing parenthesis in `PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()`.

Comment: I tried that as well and it presents but I left out the placeholder sections in my Stackoverflow post (the headers that have a cell that just says hello world). Whats strange is the app works fine when I have 4 placeholder sections (2 commented) but when all 6 are uncommented the app crashes. I've updated the post to contain the unused section headers since it seems like they are related to the issue.

Comment: if your curious comment out the bottom two section headers (Saturday and Sunday) and you'll see the app doesn't crash. but when they are uncommented the app does crash. This is really strange because I've tried doing this in a sample project but can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: actually it appears to be a swiftUI bug, I was just able to reproduce the issue in a sample project. Six section headers in a list that is inside of a NavigationView causes the app to crash

Comment: Yes, I confirm, now I can reproduce it. Time to raise a bug to Apple then :-|

Comment: yep, just filed a radar (FB6818276) thanks for your help though!

Comment: I'll do the same and reference your number two. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a bug in SwiftUI. If a list is embedded in a navigation view and has 6 or more sections the app will crash when attempting to present a sheet (FB6818276)

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t tested this, but I have had better results with .sheet by attaching it to a parent view. Try moving it so that it is a modifier of the outer VStack instead of the MealView.

Comment: just tried that, unfortunately the app still crashes. Thanks for the recommendation though